# Most efficient way to do list comprehension with filter

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and coming from Python, so list comprehensions are familiar. Take this list comprehension (please):

```
[x^2 | x <- [1..10], x^2 < 50]
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49]
```

Does the expression `x^2` get evaluated twice on every value of `x` here? Is there a way to write this comprehension such that the expression `x^2` is only evaluated once? Would it make sense to do something like this instead:

```
filter (< 50) [x^2 | x <- [1..10]]
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49]
```

Is that the more "Haskell way" of doing things? And also is it more efficient?

Comment: It depends on whether GHC decides to do [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). This looks like an easy case to me, so I expect GHC will optimise it for you (if you have optimisations turned on, of course) and the two implementations will perform identically. Someone with better low-level GHC experience than me can probably show you the generated Core and point out the optimisations. I do think your second implementation is easier to read, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd probably use a pointfree style for this: `filter (< 50) $ map (^ 2) [1..10]`

Comment: @ChrisMartin I guess I don't know how idiomatic comprehensions are in Haskell. I use them everywhere in Python. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks! Good to know that the capability exists for eliminating redundant computation.

Comment: List comprehensions also support `let` bindings: `[y | x <- [1..10], let y = x ^ 2, y < 50]`.

Comment: What @JonPurdy said. --- also, can you guess what `[y | x <- [1..], let y = x ^ 2, y < 50]` will do? (then, look at [`Data.List.takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:takeWhile)).

Comment: Let bindings! I like it.

Comment: @WillNess I am assuming this acts like a generator in Python and will only create the values necessary to meet the condition.

Comment: @EvanZamir no, it will generate all numbers one by one, and reject them, one by one. I.e. it won't know to stop by itself, and will enter into a non-productive loop when trying to produce the 8th number, which it won't ever be able to do.

Comment: @WillNess oh! That's good to know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `let` in list comprehensions:

```
[ z | x <- [1..10], let z = x^2, z < 50]
```

and then `x^2` is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it this way, which is similar to your second example:

```
filter (<50) (map (^2) [1..10])
```

I'm biased against list comprehensions.  They basically only do three things (mapping, filtering and cross products), and you want to have a much bigger vocabulary of operations than just those three.  Study the [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html) module.

As to performance, we can easily benchmark it without too much effort by using the [criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html) library.  (I've put [a repo here](https://github.com/sacundim/comprehension)—you can build this with [the Stack tool](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).)

```
import Criterion.Main

main = defaultMain
       [ bgroup "one" [ bench "10"    $ nf one 10
                      , bench "100"   $ nf one 100
                      , bench "1000"  $ nf one 1000
                      , bench "10000" $ nf one 10000
                      ]
       , bgroup "two" [ bench "10"    $ nf two 10
                      , bench "100"   $ nf two 100
                      , bench "1000"  $ nf two 1000
                      , bench "10000" $ nf two 10000
                      ]
       , bgroup "three" [ bench "10"    $ nf three 10
                        , bench "100"   $ nf three 100
                        , bench "1000"  $ nf three 1000
                        , bench "10000" $ nf three 10000
                        ]
       ]

one :: Int -> Int
one n = sum [x^2 | x <- [1..n], x^2 < n*5]

two :: Int -> Int
two n = sum (filter (<(5*n)) [x^2 | x <- [1..n]])

three :: Int -> Int
three n = sum (filter (<(5*n)) (map (^2) [1..n]))
```

I get these results, which to me suggest that it doesn't make a big difference (if any):

```
% stack install --ghc-options='-O2'
Copied executables to /Users/luis.casillas/.local/bin:
- comprehension

% comprehension
benchmarking one/10
time                 18.40 ns   (18.35 ns .. 18.45 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 18.38 ns   (18.33 ns .. 18.42 ns)
std dev              143.7 ps   (116.9 ps .. 173.6 ps)

benchmarking one/100
time                 89.11 ns   (88.49 ns .. 89.72 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 88.78 ns   (88.42 ns .. 89.44 ns)
std dev              1.582 ns   (1.231 ns .. 2.103 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 23% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking one/1000
time                 649.2 ns   (640.7 ns .. 658.7 ns)
                     0.998 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 647.6 ns   (637.8 ns .. 658.0 ns)
std dev              31.40 ns   (24.70 ns .. 40.84 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 66% (severely inflated)

benchmarking one/10000
time                 6.197 μs   (6.079 μs .. 6.282 μs)
                     0.997 R²   (0.996 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 6.180 μs   (6.058 μs .. 6.295 μs)
std dev              436.0 ns   (371.1 ns .. 531.8 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 77% (severely inflated)

benchmarking two/10
time                 20.23 ns   (19.89 ns .. 20.56 ns)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 19.89 ns   (19.71 ns .. 20.11 ns)
std dev              709.8 ps   (582.1 ps .. 939.1 ps)
variance introduced by outliers: 58% (severely inflated)

benchmarking two/100
time                 83.95 ns   (83.14 ns .. 84.90 ns)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 83.34 ns   (82.59 ns .. 83.99 ns)
std dev              2.354 ns   (1.890 ns .. 3.043 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 44% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking two/1000
time                 645.3 ns   (635.8 ns .. 655.4 ns)
                     0.998 R²   (0.997 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 652.9 ns   (643.1 ns .. 664.5 ns)
std dev              35.54 ns   (29.67 ns .. 46.19 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 71% (severely inflated)

benchmarking two/10000
time                 6.268 μs   (6.142 μs .. 6.385 μs)
                     0.998 R²   (0.997 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 6.200 μs   (6.099 μs .. 6.367 μs)
std dev              397.6 ns   (261.9 ns .. 637.4 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 73% (severely inflated)

benchmarking three/10
time                 18.96 ns   (18.66 ns .. 19.32 ns)
                     0.998 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 19.17 ns   (18.92 ns .. 19.49 ns)
std dev              990.6 ps   (774.2 ps .. 1.393 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 75% (severely inflated)

benchmarking three/100
time                 89.01 ns   (88.39 ns .. 89.78 ns)
                     0.998 R²   (0.997 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 92.60 ns   (90.78 ns .. 98.08 ns)
std dev              9.138 ns   (5.755 ns .. 14.22 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 91% (severely inflated)

benchmarking three/1000
time                 638.9 ns   (627.9 ns .. 648.7 ns)
                     0.996 R²   (0.994 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 643.6 ns   (627.9 ns .. 660.6 ns)
std dev              48.67 ns   (38.78 ns .. 61.57 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 83% (severely inflated)

benchmarking three/10000
time                 6.060 μs   (5.989 μs .. 6.119 μs)
                     0.998 R²   (0.997 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 6.124 μs   (6.036 μs .. 6.240 μs)
std dev              359.7 ns   (294.9 ns .. 431.9 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 69% (severely inflated)
```